# Mongoose - query to get all subdocuments of a document

Tags: node.js, mongoose, subdocument

I'm quite new with mongoose, I have a list of companies and each company has a subarray of users. I just want to retrieve with mongoose all users of a specific company:

a single company is like

```
{
    "_id": "57ffa47f5b70f90831212348",
    "name": "mycompany",
    "address": "...",
    "phone": "...",
    "users": [
        {
            "_id": "57ffa47f5b70f90831212347",
            "username": "alpha",
            "name": "myname",
            "surname": "mysurname",
            "password": "..."
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried with

```
Company.findOne({
        'name': req.user.name
    })

      .aggregate({$unwind: '$users'})

      .exec(
        function(err, users) {
          if (err) res.status(500).send(err);

          res.json(users);
        });
```

but I had no luck... I'm not sure how to use aggregate correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just populate company.users

```
Company.findOne({
        'name': req.user.name
    })
      .populate('users', 'username name surname')
      .exec(
        function(err, company) {
          if (err) res.status(500).send(err);

          res.json(company.users);
        });
```

Comment: thanks it works! It works also using just `.populate('users')` . Do you know where I can find a good explanation of `populate` and `aggregate` ?

Comment: Mongoose Docs of course, `populate('users')` is less secure, you might send sensitive data(password, passwod_hash)

Comment: I tried but I found it not so clear...anyway, thanks for this tip about security

Comment: also, there's no search, no nothing